# How to search for line with subprocess.check_output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a socket connection where the client submits their Windows username.  The server then runs 'net user username /domain' to find their expiration date.
I am trying to find the string "Password expires" and print that line.

```
print(line)
```

Gives me nothing.
If I use

```
print(result)
```

I do get the entire results for the command but it is kind of garbled looking.
How do I get the line with "Password expires"?  And do I need to format this a certain way so the "result" doesn't look messed up?

```
    import subprocess

    import os
    from socket import socket, gethostbyname, AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM
    import sys

    PORT_NUMBER = 3555
    SIZE = 1024

    hostName = gethostbyname( '0.0.0.0' )

    mySocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM )
    mySocket.bind( (hostName, PORT_NUMBER) )

    print ("Test server listening on port {0}\n".format(PORT_NUMBER))

    # Receive no more than 1024 bytes


    while True:
        (data,addr) = mySocket.recvfrom(SIZE)
        try:
            #print >>sys.stderr, 'Received data from', addr
            while True:
                print (data.decode())
                batcmd=('net user ' + data.decode() + ' /domain')
                result = subprocess.check_output(batcmd, shell=True)
                # print (result)  shows details but it is messy looking
                for line in result:
                    if str(line).startswith("Password expires"):
                        print (line)

    #                      if data:
    #                          print >>sys.stderr, 'sending data back to the client'
    #                          mySocket.sendto({ },addr).format(line)
    #                          # TypeError: sendto() argument 1 must be string or buffer, not dict
    #                      else:
    #                          print >>sys.stderr, 'no more data from', client_address
    #                          break

                break

            # send result back to client ?
            #mySocket.send(result.encode('ascii'))
            sys.exit()
        finally:
            print('closing socket')
            mySocket.close()
```

If I print(result), everything looks like this:

```
.local.\r\n\r\nUser Name           js83838\r\nFull Name
    John Doe       \r\n\Country Code       Comment Here.
        Account active      Locked\r\nAccount expires
            more data like this
                and this
```

**UPDATE**

I am trying this and it displays every single line instead of 1.  Every line has a b' in front of it and looks aligned properly.

```
while True:
    (data,addr) = mySocket.recvfrom(SIZE)

    #print >>sys.stderr, 'Received data from', addr
    while True:
        print (data.decode())
        batcmd=('net user ' + data.decode() + ' /domain')
        result = subprocess.check_output(batcmd, shell=True)
        # print (result)  # shows details but it is messy looking
        for line in result.splitlines():
            if str(line).find("Password expires"):
                print (line)
```

Comment: It displays results but they don't look exactly like when running the command in the cmd prompt.  Several of the lines run together and some of the lines are tabbed in further than the next.  So it looks like everything is printed at an angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subprocess.check_output` does not return lines but a buffer of bytes.

After decoding it to a string (required in Python 3):

```
result = result.decode("ascii",errors="ignore")
```

you need to split according to lines, or your loop will yield char by char, and `startswith` doesn't crash but finds nothing.

```
for line in result.splitlines():
```

does the trick. So there were 2 issues: checking whole buffer with `startswith`, and not decoding to `str` which made the searches find nothing.

Alternately, don't `decode` but do `if line.startswith(b"Password expires"):`. This makes the code compatible with Python 2 as a bonus.

Aside: be careful when parsing output of `net user` as string localization may make your program miss the information.

Comment: when I add .splitlines() is still doesn't display anything

Comment: try to print `line` and see what's printed.

Comment: I added "for line in result.splitlines():" to the code above and when I run it with the print (line), it prints the username and goes straight to "closing socket"

Comment: also tried changing startswith("Password") to contains("Password") and that gives me an error 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'

Comment: I took out try/except and it still doesn't display anything.  I changed startswith("Password expires") to find("Password expires") and it displays every single line formatted properly

Comment: It's the same code as above.  I just added .splitlines(): to make it look like "for line in result.splitlines():"  I am printing the line.  Is it saying that all of the data is in just one line?

Comment: It worked with 'startswith'  I just had to put a b' in front of the string.

Comment: yes, `subprocess.check_output` returns bytes. So displaying looks OK, but you need to decode (or use `b`Password`` to match)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that allows you to: get the output line by line, get only the line with "Password expires", not use shell=True.

```
batcmd=['net', 'user', data.decode(), '/domain')
net_process = subprocess.Popen(batcmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
grep_process= subprocess.Popen(["findstr", "Password expires"], stdin=net_process.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)  # or grep depending on your system
for line in grep_process.stdout.readlines():
    # do what you want
```

Comment: I get an error \lib\subrocess.py line 947, in __init__
line 1224, in _execute_child startupinfo) FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Ok, this is probably because grep doesn't exist in windows. Google tells me an equivalent is findstr.